# Azure Office 365 Management APIs

Tags: bash, azure, api, curl, office365

I am trying to get a response from Microsofts Office 365 Management API using bash curl commands-

I get the token like this-

```
TOKEN=$(curl -X POST "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$CLIENTID&client_secret=$ACCESSCODE&resource=$RESOURCEURL" | jq -r '.access_token')
```

And then use the token to fetch the data like this-

```
RESULT=`curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/$TENANTID/ServiceComms/Services`
```

I do get a token back with the first command, so that works fine and my tenant/client/resource strings are correct

But the second one always gives

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."
  }
}
```

I pretty sure I have access-

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the resource URL i was using did not match the URL i was requesting data from

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Are you able to expand on your answer at all?

Comment: This bit in the token request: resource=$RESOURCEURL has to match the URL you are looking to connect to (I think even the url that this post was made about is already depreciated!)

Likely its either "graph.microsoft.com" or "management.azure.com" - so whatever you request the token from has to be the same one you request the data from